# Filter only the month from date column before the slash

Tags: python, date, csv, lambda

How can I filter the month from the 7th column using `MM/DD/YYYY` format?

I currently have

```
monthlist = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']

filtered = filter(lambda p: monthlist == p[7][:1],reader)
```

It works for single digit months up until the double digit months (10,11,12).

Is it possible to just filter everything before the `/` with lambda?

edit:

reader sample:

```
                                                          Date                                                                                                 
Apple Pear Orange Cracker Honey Cheese Grape Bread Tomato 5/11/13 Lettuce Carrot
Apple Pear Orange Cracker Honey Cheese Grape Bread Tomato 4/12/13 Lettuce Carrot
Apple Pear Orange Cracker Honey Cheese Grape Bread Tomato 10/11/15 Lettuce Carrot
```

Comment: what is `reader` 's value? can you please post it with an example for better understanding

Comment: So you want to change ``MM/DD/YYYY'` to `'DD/YYYY'`?  If that's the case, you could use `date_str.split('/', 1)[1]`

Comment: @ mglison @minocha I just want to filter the the `DD`  before the  `/` on the 7th column. I think its only taking one character right now. I added a sample sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
row = 'Apple Pear Orange Cracker Honey Cheese Grape Bread Tomato 5/11/13'.split()
assert row[6] == 'Grape'  # This is the 7th column in your sample
assert row[7] == 'Bread'  # This is the column you were getting

date = row[9]
assert date == '5/11/13'

parts = date.split('/')
assert parts == ['5', '11', '13']
MM = int(parts[0])
assert MM == 5

# Doesn't matter if there's more digits
assert int('27/11/13'.split('/')[0]) == 27
```